# Cleanup warning when navigated to different screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i am getting a cleanup warning in react native i am cleaning everything. P.S.:- I get this error when i shift from one screen to another any idea ? help please Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Linking,
  Text,
  Button,
  Touchableopacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  teleconsultation_handler,
  appointmentbooked_handler,
} from '../Notification.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';
var acknowledgement, replace_brackets;
let intervalID;
let puburl;
let x = '';
const NotificationScreen = () => {
  let pressed = false;
  const [data, setdata] = useState('');
  const [url, seturl] = useState('');
  const [messageid, setmessageid] = useState('');
  const [userid, setuserid] = useState('');
  const [event, setevent] = useState('');
  const [view, setview] = useState([]);
  // const [puburl, setpuburl] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');
    console.log('data inside async storage ', value);
    if (value != null) {
      puburl = JSON.parse(value);
      let id_index = 0,
        repeat = true;
      const interval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
        if (puburl != null) {
          x = puburl[id_index].PubSubId;
          console.log('value of id >>', x);
          syncmethod(x);
          if (id_index++ >= puburl.length - 1) {
            if (repeat) id_index = 0;
            //reset
            else BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }
      }, 30000);
    }
  };

  function syncmethod(x) {
    fetch('http://')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        //console.log('TOKEN==>', data);
        pollmessage(data, x);
      });
  }

  const pollmessage = async (bearerToken, x) => {
    console.log('----------');
    let url = 'http://' + x;
    console.log('url', url);
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bearerToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('====DATA===> ', data);
        setview(data);
        replace_brackets = data.replace('[', ' ').replace(']', '');
        let localvar = JSON.parse(replace_brackets);
        // console.log(localvar);
        // console.log('event===> ', localvar.EventName);
        // console.log('message===> ', localvar.MessageText);
        // console.log('message id===> ', localvar.MessageId);
        // console.log('userid===> ', localvar.SubscriberPullIdOrPushWebHook);
        setuserid(localvar.SubscriberPullIdOrPushWebHook);
        setmessageid(localvar.MessageId);
        setevent(localvar.EventName);
        if (localvar.MessageText) {
          let splitted_msg, splitted_url;
          if (localvar.MessageText.includes('$')) {
            splitted_url = localvar.MessageText.split('$').pop();
            splitted_msg = localvar.MessageText.substring(
              0,
              localvar.MessageText.indexOf('$'),
            );
          } else {
            splitted_msg = localvar.MessageText;
            splitted_url = null;
          }
          setdata(splitted_msg);
          seturl(splitted_url);
          console.log('-----------------');
          console.log('MESSAGE===> ', splitted_msg);
          console.log('URL==> ', splitted_url);
          switch (localvar.EventName) {
            case 'Appointment_BooKed':
              appointmentbooked_handler(localvar.EventName, splitted_msg);
              break;

            case 'Tele_Consultation':
              teleconsultation_handler(localvar.EventName, splitted_msg);
              break;

            case 'default':
              break;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.log('ERROR during polling for messages ===> ', err),
      );
  };

  function gotourl() {
    if (!pressed) {
      pressed = true;
      console.log('url===> ', url);

      if (url != null) {
        console.log('url===> ', url);
        Linking.openURL(url);
      }
      acknowledgement = JSON.stringify({
        ack: {
          UserId: userid,
          EventId: messageid,
          EventName: event,
          EventStatus: 'Accepted',
        },
      });
      sendack();
    } else {
      alert('System has already acknowledged');
    }
  }

  const deleteItem = index => {
    if (!pressed) {
      pressed = true;
      acknowledgement = JSON.stringify({
        ack: {
          UserId: userid,
          EventId: messageid,
          EventName: event,
          EventStatus: 'Rejected',
        },
      });
      sendack();
    } else {
      alert('System has already acknowledged');
    }
  };
  function sendack() {
    fetch('http://')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        sendacknowledgement(data);
      });
  }
  function sendacknowledgement(beatoken) {
    console.log('inside send ack token ====>>>>', beatoken);
    console.log('acknowledgement===>', acknowledgement);
    // console.log(event)
    // console.log( messageid)
    let url = 'https:' + x;
    console.log('ack url  =>', url);
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + beatoken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },

      body: acknowledgement,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log('ACK Response: ', data))
      .catch(err =>
        console.log('ERROR DURING SENDING ACKNOWLEDGEMENT ===> ', err),
      );
  }

  // console.log('data..', view.length);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {view.length <= 3 ? (
        <>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>NO NEW MESSAGES</Text>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{data}</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => gotourl()} title="Accept" color="green" />
          <Button onPress={() => deleteItem()} title="Delete" color="red" />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2c3e58',
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  separatorLine: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  emptyContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#1b262c',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  heading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#00b7c2',
    marginVertical: 15,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  actionButton: {
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  seasonName: {
    color: '#fdcb9e',
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
  listItem: {
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default Notif
```

Comment: Seems like you need to clear the interval when the component unmounts. You can use a cleanup function in effect hook. But it would need interval ID to do that.

Comment: can you give a demo soln??@AjeetShah

Comment: Try this after storing "interval" in a ref object using [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. `useEffect(() => { getData(); return () => { BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(interval.current); } }, []);`

Comment: useRef(interval);  should be inside useffect or getData() function@AjeetShah

Comment: Add `const interval = useRef()` at top where you have many `useState`s. Then, write `interval.current = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {` inside `getData` function. Make sure to take time to read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) on it.

Comment: but it would be timer inside a timer see my getdata function would it not overlap?@AjeetShah

Comment: There is only **1** usage of timer i.e. `const interval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(()` in your code. And, I suggested replacing your code with my code, so why would it overlap?

Comment: because i am clearing interval  inside getdata () function already so i asked .? can i clear it in both useffect and getdata@AjeetShah

Comment: Yes. You can clear more than once. But it would, in fact, clear only once whichever occurred earlier. BTW, does this eliminates the warning (original question)?

Comment: yes it eliminates the warning thanks !!@AjeetShah, ...on a completely different note do you have any idea how to implement headless JS in react native their documentation is something i was not able to understand ...!!!

Comment: No. I don't know enough of React Native. But you should read (and write code) the docs, https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android, again & again until it makes sense.